# Add class on unique tabindex in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

i have a form coming from wordpress plugin, there i'm repeating some fields and recently i did that on clicking "+" icon it clones the fields and and when i enter numeric values in those fields it adds them and displays them.
Now the problem is that i had total 4 repeaters and those 4 repeater's "+" have a same class on which i'm performing function to add class and iterate over them to calculate the input.
But the only unique thing i have in "+" icon is that it's "tabindex" so is there any way that in jquery that on bases of tabindex i should perform functionality ?
Currently i tried to do this but didn't help:

```
jQuery('.gf_repeater_add').click(function(){
     var member1 = jQuery('.gf_repeater_add').attr("tabindex");
     //gets the tabindex

    //now the thing which isn't working, because i don't know how to let it know that e.g 23 is tabindex
    jQuery(member1).on("click", function(){
   for (var count=0; count<=10; count++) {
      jQuery("#input_1_59-1-"+count).addClass('member1');
   }
   });

});
```

Comment: Why are you using click inside click ? And you need to user 
jQuery(".gf_repeater_add[tabindex='"+member1+"']") instead of jQuery(member1). Because member1 is not selector its just integer number of tabindex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery selector containing attribute. In your case it should look something like this:
`jQuery('div[TabIndex="'+member1+'"]').on("click", function(){`

You can read more about attribute selector at official jQuery doc [here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

Comment: it's input field, and how do we give exact number in tab index ? e.g will it be like `jQuery('input[tabindex=49]').click()` ?

Comment: Yes you can use `jQuery('input[tabindex=49]').click()` or any other selector you have. Eg. if you have class you can use `jQuery('.class[tabindex=49]').click()`